# Delete rows based on char in the index string

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 1), index=['mark13', 'luisgimenez', 'miguel72', 'luis34'],columns=['probability'])


             probability
mark13         -1.054687
luisgimenez     0.081224
miguel72       -0.893619
luis34         -1.576941
```

I would like to remove the rows where the last character in the index string does not contain a number .

The desired output would look something like this :
(dropping the row where the index does not finishes with a number)

```
             probability
mark13         -1.054687
miguel72       -0.893619
luis34         -1.576941
```

I am sure the direction I need to get is the `boolean indexing` but I do not know how could I reference the last character in the index name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#use isdigt to check last char of your index to be used as a mask array to filter rows.
df[[e[-1].isdigit() for e in df.index]]
Out[496]: 
          probability
mark13      -0.111338
miguel72     0.548725
luis34       0.682949
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the str accessor to check if the last character is a number:

```
df[df.index.str[-1].str.isdigit()]
Out: 
          probability
mark13      -0.350466
miguel72     1.220434
luis34      -0.962123
```